# Show there's no RAA-free derivation of $(P_1\to P_2)\lor (P_2\to P_1)$

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus, natural-deduction

Show there's no RAA-free derivation of $(P_1\to P_2)\lor (P_2\to P_1)$. (Hint: Look for a normal such derivation.)

***Solution:***

Here are the theorems we have learnt from the normal deduction chapter.

---

**Theorem 1 (Glivenkos theorem):** Every derivation can be transformed so that in the end it becomes a derivation in which RAA does not occur except possible at the last step, and in which all undischarged assumptions occurred (as undischarged assumptions) in the original derivation.

**Theorem 2.** If $Γ\to ⊥$, then there exists an RAA-free derivation from Γ to ⊥.

**Theorem 3 (weak normalization):** Every derivation can be transformed in
such a way that a normal derivation is reached, in which all undischarged assumptions
existed already (as undischarged assumptions) in the original derivation.
If the original derivation was RAA-free then the resulting derivation consists
only on the rules that were used in the original one.

**Theorem 4:** If a normal derivation ends in an elimination rule, then the main premise is a subformula in some undischarged assumption.

**Theorem 5 (subformula property):** In every normal derivation without RAA, every formula is a subformula of either the conclusion or one of the undischarged assumptions of the derivation.

**Theorem 6:** Assume that $Γ\vdash ϕ$.

1. If $ϕ$ is a ∧-formula, then there is a normal derivation from $Γ$ to $ϕ$ which ends with $∧I$.
2. If $ϕ$ is a →-formula, then there is a normal derivation from $Γ$ to $ϕ$ which
   ends with →I.

---

So let's assume there's a normal RAA-free derivation. At this point I would say that the last theorem won't help me. Neither won't, I guess, the first or second theorem. I have already used the third Theorem so the only theorems which are left to use is **Theorem 4** and **Theorem 5**?

> A little side note: A friend to me told me, when I have an or-formula, then I NEED to end with an $\lor$-introduction. And if I then have an implication rule then I NEED to use an $\to$-introduction.
>
> It would look like this $\frac{\frac{P_2}{P_1\to P_2}\to I}{(P_1\to
> > P_2)\lor (P_2\to P_1)}\lor I.$
>
> But I have not seen, or at least I think so, any theorem which states I have to end with an or introduction rule if my conclusion is an or-formula. Neither do I know why the only possibility (in a general case) is to use an implication introduction as my second last rule. I don't know if he thinks that theorem 6 says that if you have an implication formula then you have to use implication introduction. Perhaps he has misread the theorem. Because it really says that if $\phi$ is an implication formula then it has to end with an implication introduction (also my $\phi$ is an or-formula).

So perhaps I can use the subformula property and show it can't hold? I am a little rusty when it comes to this kind of exercises. I know my goal but sometimes it's pretty hard for me to end up there. I think it would be pretty simple if my tree in the yellow box were correct, but I don't think it is correct. Any help would be appreciated. Perhaps, if it is possible, some help how to think if I try to solve other similar problems. Where should i start? How should I think? Perhaps I only have to solve many problems? Thank you :)

Comment: I've found an hint [here](http://www.helsinki.fi/~negri/dresum.pdf), page 9 : **9. Applications of normalization**.

Comment: Your formula is a substitution instance of ((A $\rightarrow$ B) $\lor$ (C $\rightarrow$ A)).  Consequently, if ((A $\rightarrow$ B) $\lor$ (C $\rightarrow$ A)) consists of an axiom, or can get derived without RAA, there *does* exist an RAA-free derivation of your formula.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Hint*

See :

- Dirk van Dalen, [Logic and Structure](https://books.google.it/books?id=u0wlXPHATDcC&pg=PA204) (5th ed - 2013), page 204 for *intuitionistic logic* :

> **Theorem 7.3.11** Let $Γ \vdash  ϕ ∨ ψ$, where $Γ$ does not contain $∨$ in strictly positive subformulas, then $Γ \vdash ϕ$ or $Γ \vdash ψ$

Thus, if $(P \to Q) \lor (Q \to P)$ is derivable without *RAA*, the derivation would hold intuitionistically.

Applying the above Theorem with $\Gamma = \emptyset$, we would conclude that :

> either $\vdash ( P \to Q)$ or $\vdash (Q \to P)$

but neither are intuitionistically *valid*.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer, I really understand it and how to solve it with that approach. I am just unsure if I would be allowed to use that method on an exam since, I think, that theorem isn't in our textbook :).

Comment: Sorry, I am still pretty stuck but i won't give up ;). Since I have no assumptions perhaps i can reason as follows: "Since $\vdash (P_1\to P_2)\lor (P_2\to P_1)$, hence I have no assumptions, it can't end in an elimination rule. That is, I can exclude theorem 4"? Perhaps this helps me to exclude theorem 5? A little side-note again: If i know that it 'can't' end in an elimination rule do i then know that the main premise can't be the conclusion in some undischarged assumption? Thanks :)).